# Having troubles with razor inside html inside razor

Tags: razor

i'm having syntax issues with a 'razor inside html inside razor if statement' Where is the problem with my code ?

This is for a login page

```
@ {
    ViewBag.Title = "UserDashBoard";
}

< fieldset >
    < legend > User DashBoard < /legend>

@if (Session["UserName"] != null)
{< text >
    Welcome @Session["UserName"].ToString() < /text>
    } < /fieldset>
```

error in line 8 missing '}'

Comment: Well, you've got an awful lot of white space in your tags for one thing... Pretty sure Razor's not going to recognize `< /text>` (with a space between `<` and `/`)...

Comment: Yea remove all white spaces in your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you it was all about blank spaces

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserDashBoard";
}

<fieldset>
    <legend> User DashBoard </legend>

@if (Session["UserName"] != null)
{<text>
    Welcome @Session["UserName"].ToString() </text>
    } </fieldset>
```

i feel dumb...